# Ms Access query to SQL Server - DistinctRow

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

What would the syntax be to convert this MS Access query to run in SQL Server as it doesn't have a DistinctRow keyword

```
UPDATE DISTINCTROW [MyTable] 
INNER JOIN [AnotherTable] ON ([MyTable].J5BINB = [AnotherTable].GKBINB) 
                          AND ([MyTable].J5BHNB = [AnotherTable].GKBHNB) 
                          AND ([MyTable].J5BDCD = [AnotherTable].GKBDCD) 
SET [AnotherTable].TessereCorso = [MyTable].[J5F7NR];
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I'm not familiar with `DISTINCTROW`, but it seems that it wouldn't have any effect at all here in an `UPDATE`. Should the query update `AnotherTable` with the "first" `J5F7NR` value in `MyTable`? If there are multiple rows without the `DISTINCTROW`, are they all the same - or is `J5F7NR` different?

Comment: I think we might need some data to help us with this. In Access can you run 2 queries and post the data: `select [MyTable].* from [MyTable] inner join [AnotherTable]...` and `select [AnotherTable].* from [MyTable] inner join [AnotherTable]...` using the join criteria from above in both? We will need to see at least the 3 join key values. Like @StevenHibble I struggle with the use and expected outcome of `distinct` or `distinctrow` in an `Update` statement.

Comment: If you can give sample data in a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), that behaves differently with and without DISTINCTROW in Access, you will probably get a quick answer.

Answer (score 4):

DISTINCTROW [MyTable] removes duplicate MyTable entries from the results. Example:

```
select distinctrow items 
  items.item_number, items.name
from items
join orders on orders.item_id = items.id;
```

In spite of the join getting you the same item_number and name multiple times when there is more than one order for it, DISTINCTROW reduces this to one row per item. So the whole join is merely for assuring that you only select items for which exist at least one order. You don't find DISTINCTROW in any other DBMS as far as I know. Probably because it is not needed. When checking for existence, we use `EXISTS` of course (or `IN` for that matter).

You are joining MyTable and AnotherTable and expect for some reason to get the same MyTable record multifold for one AnotherTable record, so you use DISTINCTROW to only get it once. Your query would (hopefully) fail if you got two *different* MyTable records for one AnotherTable record.

What the update does is:

```
update anothertable
set tesserecorso = (select top 1 j5f7nr from mytable where mytable.j5binb = anothertable.gkbinb and ...)
where exists       (select *            from mytable where mytable.j5binb = anothertable.gkbinb and ...)
```

But this uses about the same subquery twice. So we'd want to update from a query instead.

The easiest way to get one result record per <some columns> in a standard SQL query is to aggregate data:

```
select *
from anothertable a
join 
(
  select j5binb, j5bhnb, j5bdcd, max(j5f7nr) as j5f7nr
  from mytable
  group by j5binb, j5bhnb, j5bdcd
) m on  m.j5binb = a.gkbinb and m.j5bhnb = a.gkbhnb and m.j5bdcd = a.gkbdcd;
```

How to write an updateble query is different from one DBMS to another. Here is the final update statement for SQL-Server:

```
update a
set a.tesserecorso = m.j5f7nr
from anothertable a
join 
(
  select j5binb, j5bhnb, j5bdcd, max(j5f7nr) as j5f7nr
  from mytable
  group by j5binb, j5bhnb, j5bdcd
) m on m.j5binb = a.gkbinb and m.j5bhnb = a.gkbhnb and m.j5bdcd = a.gkbdcd;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`DISTINCTROW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177882(v=office.12).aspx) predicate in MS Access SQL removes duplicates across all fields of a table in join statements and not just the selected fields of query (which `DISTINCT` in practically all SQL dialects do). So consider selecting all fields in a derived table with `DISTINCT` predicate:

```
UPDATE [AnotherTable]
SET [AnotherTable].TessereCorso = main.[J5F7NR]
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT m.* FROM [MyTable] m) As main
INNER JOIN [AnotherTable]
    ON  (main.J5BINB = [AnotherTable].GKBINB) 
    AND (main.J5BHNB = [AnotherTable].GKBHNB) 
    AND (main.J5BDCD = [AnotherTable].GKBDCD)
```

Comment: Close but no cigar... The original query updates 38 rows. this one updates 35

Comment: Well it was an educated guess! Without table structure, data, and their relationships, hard to test.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update [AnotherTable]
Set [AnotherTable].TessereCorso = MyTable.[J5F7NR]
From [AnotherTable]
Inner Join
(
    Select Distinct [J5BINB],[5BHNB],[J5BDCD]
    ,(Select Top 1 [J5F7NR] From MyTable) as [J5F7NR]
    ,[J5BHNB]
    From MyTable
)as MyTable
On  (MyTable.J5BINB = [AnotherTable].GKBINB) 
AND (MyTable.J5BHNB = [AnotherTable].GKBHNB) 
AND (MyTable.J5BDCD = [AnotherTable].GKBDCD)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant of the query.. (Too lazy to get the original tables).
But like the query above updates 35 rows =, so does this one

```
UPDATE [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati]
SET 
[Albi-Anagrafe-Associati].CRegDitte = [055- Registri ditte].[CRegDitte], 
[Albi-Anagrafe-Associati].NIscrTribunale = [055- Registri ditte].[NIscrTribunale], 
[Albi-Anagrafe-Associati].NRegImprese = [055- Registri ditte].[NRegImprese]
FROM  [055- Registri ditte]
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [055- Registri ditte]-- [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati] 
    WHERE ([055- Registri ditte].GIBINB = [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati].GKBINB) 
    AND ([055- Registri ditte].GIBHNB = [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati].GKBHNB) 
    AND ([055- Registri ditte].GIBDCD = [Albi-Anagrafe-Associati].GKBDCD))
```