# Updating DISTINCTROW in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

This was originally an Access query updating DISTINCTROW. I cannot seem to find an equivalent way to do this in SQL Server. Is it even possible? As it is written in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE CustOrder
SET  CustOrder.YARDS = QUANTITY * Lkp_Codes.VOLUME_GALS * 0.00495113
FROM CustOrder 
INNER JOIN Lkp_ServiceCodes as Lkp_Codes
ON CustOrder.SERVICE_CODE = Lkp_Codes.[SVC CODE]
```

Comment: What's wrong with your query?

Comment: I don’t think anything actually is wrong with it. I’m trying to convert some access sql to sql server, but I don’t really think DISTINCTROW will make a difference. I’m actually confused as to why they did distinctrow in the first place. Forgive my, im pretty new to this.

Comment: If you have a duplicates and you don't want to update more than 1 row then you can use a CTE.

Comment: http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/distinct_vs_distinctrow/unique_values_records.asp

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715672/ms-access-query-to-sql-server-distinctrow