# MS Access UPDATE query very slow

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I have a very simple UPDATE query in Access which should update the underlying SQL Server. For whatever reason, Access does not pass the query to server but handles it by itself, i.e., it does an update query for each row. Since the table is huge, this runs forever.

This is the query as generated with the editor.

```sql
UPDATE dbo_myTable
SET dbo_myTable.myColumn = 'A'
WHERE dbo_myTable.myOtherColumn = 123;
```

If I run the same query as pure SQL it takes only seconds - as expected.

```sql
UPDATE dbo.myTable
SET dbo.myTable.myColumn = 'A'
WHERE dbo.myTable.myOtherColumn = 123;
```

The problem is not the `'A'` value. If I change it from `'A'` to `Null` the problem remains.

### Background:

My actual update query is more complicated and involves joins and multiple conditions. While debugging the speed issues I could break it down to the above simple query which is already slow.

I used the SQL Server Profiler to confirm my guess that access does a query for each row instead of passing the whole query to the SQL Server.

### Related:

I had a similar question a while ago: [Force MS Access to send full query to SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866769/force-ms-access-to-send-full-query-to-sql-server/58866985) . While the problem is the same - Access not passing the whole query - the solution has to be different because here there are really no special commands whatsoever here.

Comment: What is the data type of _myOtherColumn_?

Comment: Perhaps you miss an index on _myOtherColumn_?

Comment: myOtherColumn contains integer values. It also has an index. But since the query runns blazing fast if passed-through the problem has to be somewehere in Access. If myOtherColumn=123 results in ~100.000 rows, Access takes minues, while the pass-through query finishes in ~3 seconds. (The MS SQL server has enough RAM to fit the whole table in RAM - actually enough to fit roughly 1/4 of the DB in RAM).

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for update queries in Access is significantly different from that of SQL server, especially regarding joins. They can't be handed off to SQL server.

One of the main differences is that in Access, an update query write locks all included tables by default and can write to all of them, while in SQL server, you have a separate `FROM` section, and the query only write locks and writes to a single table.

Instead, use a passthrough query to execute an update query on SQL server if performance is an issue.

Comment: But here there is only one table and no joins.

Comment: That's not relevant. The syntax for update queries is different between SQL server and Access. Afaik Access doesn't attempt to translate or pass the query directly to SQL server, even if this one is simple enough that it could feasibly do this. But then again, I rarely execute update queries this simple.

Comment: I can't imagine how this simple query could be modified/transformed in any way. Thus, it should be passed _as is_ to SQL Server having the SQL equivalent to that of the pass-through query.

Comment: It could be modified in a very simple way (like most Access `UPDATE` queries are): it gets translated to a `SELECT` query, and then each row is updated separately on SQL server. And that's exactly what the OP said in his question. And of course, this is very much suboptimal on large datasets. If you have another explanation, feel free to post your own answer, though.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. Access does exactly what @ErikA descibes. But what to do about it? I tried different Access Versions (2003, 2016, 2019) all do it alike.

Comment: Not sure if syntax differences are a main part of the reason, but Access never passes UDPATE queries to the server, but handles them itself. It also wants to show the message box "You are about to update xyz records, Yes/No?", which wouldn't be possible otherwise. -- The solution is as Erik writes: **Use a Pass-Through query** to update larger sets of data.

Comment: @Andre: The total update is wrapped in a transaction by Access, so it is possible. I guess though, that `db.Execute` uses autocommit as you cannot regret that.

Comment: @Andre: _each row is updated separately on SQL server._ I've checked this with people having more knowledge than me, and Erik is right. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can fool Access to call a *bulk update*:

```vb
Sql = "UPDATE dbo.myTable SET dbo.myTable.myColumn = 'A' WHERE dbo.myTable.myOtherColumn = 123;"
CurrentDb.Execute Sql, dbQSPTBulk
```

> The above dbqQSPTBulk is  supposed to be used with dbQSQLPassthough
>   but you don’t have to.
>
> If you use above, then only one update command is sent.

Credit: *Albert Kallal*